# CAPCOM Console at Mercury Control Center; what does "Desired Retrofire Setting" time display mean?

Tags: nasa, identify-this-object, mission-control, project-mercury

Wikipedia's [Cape Canaveral Air Force Station](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cape_Canaveral_Air_Force_Station) page links to the image [Alan Shepard in Mercury Control Center](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Alan_Shepard_in_Mercury_Control_Center.jpg) (shown below).

The console has two large digital time displays. One is dedicated GMT but the other is labeled Desired Retrofire Setting and there are three buttons below it with the same label.

What would the time display show, and what does the label mean?

[image: Mercury Control Center cropped] [image: Mercury Control Center cropped]

[image: Alan Shepard in Mercury Control Center]

[Source](https://www.nasa.gov/centers/kennedy/images/content/423084main_Shannahs_11_full.jpg)

Comment: 92.4% sure that "DESIRED RETROFIRE SETTING" is one phrase, not three options. The buttons on the lower right of the display have individual labels beneath.

Comment: Educated guess: the buttons select one of three computed retrofire times to be displayed at the top of the panel. Leftmost one would be the nominal, pre-planned retrofire time; middle would be an early return (label could be something like LAND IN NEXT ORBIT); rightmost would be an nearly immediate retrofire (labeled EMERGENCY). In this photo no retrofire time has been computed, for whatever reason, so it's displaying 00:00:00. Retrofire is a pretty timing-critical operation, so it would make sense that CAPCOM would want to see it next to the current time.

Comment: The first label could be something like NORMAL REENTRY or NOMINAL REENTRY.

Comment: This is a Mercury-era console, so analysis of the Apollo code is going to be of limited utility.

Comment: Ah, should have looked more carefully.  Disregard my previous comment.

Comment: I'm almost tempted to write a script that blurrily renders candidate texts (using Coniglio [Sublime](https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/coniglio/sublime/)) and compares them to the button labels in the photo.

Comment: I’d perspective correct the target/reference images first rather than distorting the candidate renders — do it once instead of N times. Adding noise would be counterproductive for finding the best match.

Comment: @RussellBorogove It's probably okay if you post your educated guess as a tentative answer. It doesn't look like people are rushing to post more authoritatively-sourced answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [Project Mercury Second Interim Report,](https://books.google.com/books?id=br4jAQAAMAAJ&pg=RA1-PA60&lpg=RA1-PA60&dq=mercury%20retrofire%20normal%20reentry%20emergency%20display&source=bl&ots=X3OUe-emaP&sig=ACfU3U1rwUVGMUpV2JXEYYIjOc197dLDqA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi2ocG39pH1AhUVbs0KHRL8DFoQ6AF6BAgkEAM#v=onepage&q=mercury%20retrofire%20normal%20reentry%20emergency%20display&f=false):

> The retrocontroller panel displays the retrofiring times for normal reentry, end of each orbit, and emergency landing areas. These retrofiring times are calculated at the Goddard Computing Center.

The labels on the buttons in the lower right correspond to these times: "NORMAL REENTRY" on the left, "END OF THIS ORBIT" (or something similar) in the middle, and "EMERGENCY" on the right.

So my understanding would be that the DESIRED RETROFIRE SETTING would show one of three time-marks at which the spacecraft could execute retrofire and begin the process of reentry.

The picture appears to be taken during liftoff; until stable orbit is achieved, retrofire times wouldn't be computable, which would explain the 00:00:00 time display despite "NORMAL REENTRY" being selected.

During a nominal mission, I assume the "NORMAL REENTRY" time would be displayed; if a problem required the mission to be cut short without a very urgent need to reenter, the "END OF THIS ORBIT" time would be selected, putting the returning spacecraft in or near the planned recovery area, and if there was a more urgent problem, "EMERGENCY" would be selected to time reentry for one of a small number of emergency landing zones.